# ActiveMerchant Poodle patch for PayPal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, paypal, activemerchant, poodle-attack

I'm using Rails 3, ActiveMerchant 1.5.1 gem, and PayPal express. Since recently I can't get my payments work through PayPal, continue to receive this error

**OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed**

I believe this is related to [PayPal response to Poodle](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/PayPal-Forward/PayPal-Response-to-SSL-3-0-Vulnerability-aka-POODLE/ba-p/891829). Is there any patch for ActiveMerchant  to address these PayPal changes or the SSL 3.0 Vulnerability in general?

Comment: Might be you need to change the SSL connection to TLS . You can find more info here regarding moving to TLS connections: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/SSL/SSLContext.html

Comment: See the conversation here: https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/pull/1434

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Eshan I found that Net::Http can be forced to use specific protocol during connection. That's how I patched my version of ActiveMerchant

```
def configure_ssl(http)
  ...

  http.use_ssl = true

  http.ssl_version = :TLSv1  # poodle vulnarability fix

  ...
end
```

For those who have a newer version of ActiveMerchant, I think upgrading to the master, as suggested by Davidslv, should work.

Answer (score 1):

We are having the same problems, and we are looking into using the activemerchant from master branch instead of rubygems since there's a commit that "fixes" this.

Comment: can you give us a link to that commit?

Comment: is it this one?https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/commit/187cead7093e20e4738b51e5ac012dc5840b87dd

Comment: We added a PR for it and then we got told it was a one off given Paypal messed up in some configuration, read more here: https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/pull/1434